# Prevent Spilling when using position fixed

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an annoying issue with overlapping two divs. I'm using a parallax js for a responsive background, I also have a jumbotron (bootstrap 3) over the top. When I scroll down my page the jumbotron follows and spills onto content below. I'm wanting to keep the jumbotron on top of my parallax background. Sorry if this sounds confusing, i'm not one for giving up but i may have bitten off more than I can chew lol. Any help is greatly appreciated :-) thanks

Code so far:

```
 HTML:

  <div class="jumbotron"> 
    <div class="row text-center">

            <h1>Fashionable Fondants</h1>
            <h3>"developing your <span>creative side"</span></h3>
            <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Who We Are</a>
        </div>

               </div><!-- end jumbotron -->
                <div class="bg" data-ibg-bg="img/bg.jpg"> 
                        </div><!-- end bg -->
```

CSS:

```
    .bg {
      height: 760px;
      width: 100%;
      margin: none;
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      overflow: hidden;}

     .jumbotron{
       position: fixed;
       background: none;
       max-height: 800px;
       padding: 0px 0;
       z-index: 2;
       width: 100%;
       margin-top: 10%;}
```

The Parallax plugin im using is found here: https://github.com/peachananr/interactive_bg

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: Hi alireza safian, thank you. I have uploaded everything to jsfiddle but cant get background img up. Thank you for your time.

https://jsfiddle.net/L0fd14y2/3/

Comment: Please, fix your jsfiddle(Paste your resources correctly).

Comment: OK I have now pasted all the resources, however my image is still not displaying. The parallax plugin uses "data-ibg-bg="img/bg.jpg" code to display it along with the JS that i have uploaded. jsfiddle doesn't display the image and I have tried posting the url in many forms with no luck. 

As you can see though, the jombotron spills onto the content below. This is my first time using jsfiddle so i may have not uploaded it right, I will keep fiddling. https://jsfiddle.net/q4ojctqg/

Comment: Please, check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/q4ojctqg/3/). So what is your problem?

Comment: The issue is when you scroll down the jumbotron spills out onto the content below. it doesn't stay contained over the parallax background.

Answer (score 0):

You have set your jumbotron to position:fixed.  So it's doing exactly what you asked it to do.  You must remove position:fixed.

Now if you wish the jumbotron to be placed in the first 100% of screen height, then create a fake container.   Place html and body height to 100%.  Make the fake container position:relative, so you may position the jumbotron inside it.

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
.fake-body { height:100%; position:relative; }
.jumbotron {
    background: none;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute; top:50%; margin-top:-200px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L0fd14y2/7/

For reference: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: Hi Jennifer, sorry for the late reply. Thank you loads that worked a treat!!!  I have no idea why I put position:fixed, my fault for copying and pasting code rather than looking at it logically. Putting a fake-body div in-place has also fixed my other div layouts. Again thank you :-)